# Facebook Plugin Like Facebook Plugin Error

Tags: html, facebook-javascript-sdk

The button is displayed on the page and everything is ok, but when you click, it seems like I take the likes, and then the word bug is placed in small letters instead of the button.

I click on the error and facebook notifies: This function is not available .: There was an error processing this request. Please try again later.

The strange thing is that the share button that comes with that plugin does work. I leave the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div 
    class='fb-like'
    data-href='http://www.ejemplo.blogspot.com'
    data-layout='standard'
    data-action='like'
    data-size='large'
    data-show-faces='true'
    data-share="true">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Testing in the Like button configurator, it asks me to explicitly confirm that I want to like this URL. This can f.e. happen if you have been testing excessively, so that Facebook’s algorithms think something shady is going on. It will go away automatically, once enough real users have confirmed that they indeed intended to like that URL.

Comment: I have tested with the same code as the Facebook Developers page and I throw the same error. :(

Comment: Logging in from the Like button, if it works. But refreshing the page, or having previously logged in does not work. :(